# Is it possible to link/group rows in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

Is it possible to link multiple rows in MySQL? By link I mean like this:

```
ItemID  Status                        ItemID  Status

     1, Available   Result needed ->       1, Unavailable

     2, Available                          2, Unavailable
```

If the status of Row 2 is updated to "Unavailable", is it possible to force on row 1 and change it to?

I need this to create groups with multiple rows in them.

Comment: Not unless you've defined some kind of relationship between the rows; or unless it's a simple arithmetic relationship

Comment: How these rows are related ? What is the logic behind this logic ?

Comment: @MarkBaker I will look it up.

Comment: They should have a common key/value stored in the db you can then use

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty Well my DB is full of different instruments, and some instruments have multiple parts. I want these instruments with multiple parts to be together.

Answer (score 1):

You can design your DB into 3 tables

1. Items : This table will have item details with ItemID as primary Key
2. Statuses : This table will have all available statuses in the system with a StatusID as primary Key
3. ItemStatus : This is a combination of Items & Statuses table. And has ItemID & StatusID

Comment: Isn't it possible to create a column for this instead? Seems quite sketchy to create multiple tables when I've already got most of my database built